# Grub Not showing any OS and no options will open

Tags: windows-10, grub2

I am receiving this error when I open any option that isn't sub-menus 
"error symbol grub_file_filters not found"
I tried dual booting parrot os and then when restarting grub came up but no [OS](https://i.imgur.com/C2PWSLN_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium).

Comment: How long had the dual boot configuration been working before it failed? Anything noticed out of the ordinary before this problem was discovered?

Comment: @K7AAY , It's only been working today and I didn't notice anything different. All I did was restart my computer because before the restart I didn't even have the grub bootloader enabled/installed.